# Method 'List' of object 'CommandBarComboBox' failed

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Method 'List' of object 'CommandBarComboBox' failed ---Earlier using 2011 mac excel, when updated to 2015 getting this error. desperatly required solution...
code is

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UndoList As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Get the undo List to capture the last action performed by user
    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

    '~~> Check if the last action was not a paste nor an autofill
    If Left(UndoList, 5) <> "Paste" And UndoList <> "Auto Fill" _
    Then GoTo LetsContinue

    '~~> Undo the paste that the user did but we are not clearing
    '~~> the clipboard so the copied data is still in memory
    Application.Undo

    If UndoList = "Auto Fill" Then Selection.Copy

    '~~> Do a pastespecial to preserve formats
    On Error Resume Next
    '~~> Handle text data copied from a website
    Target.Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", _
    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Retain selection of the pasted data
    Union(Target, Selection).Select

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't replicate the error in Excel 2016, but I do observe that if this code is run in a new/fresh instance of Excel, then there is nothing present in the `List` and I get an "Unspecified Error". Is it possible that your scenario has nothing in the Undo stack?

Comment: you made no mention where the code crashes, and i can't see your computer screen from here.